# NullPointerException in JSP with Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat

That's my code in jsp when i run it a get an error as below. I am using tomcat . I really want to know what may be the cause of this problem?

test.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="admin.User"%>
<%@page import="admin.ConnectionManager"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title> test </title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
        <table>
            <%
            ResultSet rs = User.loadAll(); 
                while (rs.next()) { 
            %> 

            <tr>
               <TH>ID</TH>
               <TH>Name</TH>
               <TH>Surname</TH>
               <TH>Email</TH>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td> <%= rs.getInt(1) %> </td>
               <td> <%= rs.getString(2) %> </td>
               <td> <%= rs.getString(3) %> </td>
               <td> <%= rs.getString(4) %> </td>


           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

       <% 
           } 
       %>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

---

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:75)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs.
```

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36

Comment: Try wrapping your while loop in a null check, to see if you're actually getting a result back from your user load: `if (rs != null) {...`

Comment: What exactly is null? Trace your exception.

Comment: Check the test_jsp.java file that is located under Tomcat/work directory. It is your JSP file translated to java and on the line 75 you will recognize your own java code you inserted into the JSP page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426710/http-status-500-java-lang-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again; you can edit your original.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the Apache Tomcat logs for that, but probably User.loadAll() is returning null which is set to rs and the NullPointerException is thrown on rs.next()

by the way, either body and html are not closed or you just mis-copied the code.

Comment: yes i closed them. thats the method                                 public static ResultSet loadAll() {
  return query("SELECT * FROM user");
 }    what should i do in order not to return null

Comment: when i go into apache tomcat logs there is no file , is that because i developing my app via Eclipse ? How can i check them from eclipse?

Comment: The logs should be there, are you using an eclipse plugin to start/shutdown Tomcat? Well in fact did you manage to solve your issue?